# How to update the attribute type in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, upgrade

I have to change the type of an attribute from text to decimal. I used upgrade script below. But it is not working

```
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }


    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    { 
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

            $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'as_low_as', 'frontend_input','decimal', null);
        }
    }
}
```

How can we update the attribute type of an existing attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','frontend_input','text');
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','backend_type','decimal');
```

- Frontend input should be text
- Backend type should be decimal

If wanting it to be a price, don't forget to add backend model: `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price`. And `frontend_input` should be `price`, `backend_type` should be `decimal`.

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'as_low_as', 'frontend_input','price', null);
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','backend_type','decimal');
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','backend_model','Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price');
```

**[EDIT]**

We can remove the old one, and add new one:

```
 if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4', '<')) {
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityType, 'as_low_as');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            'catalog_product',
            'as_low_as',
            [
                'label' => 'As Low As',
                'input' => 'price',
                'type' => 'decimal',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: When I update like this, It's value is stored as null in flat table.

Comment: One more question, do you want to add price attribute?

Comment: Did you allow showing this attribute in catalog product listing?

Comment: Yes, I need as price attribute. Yes I'm allowing this in listing

Comment: Check my updated answer for pricing attribute.

Comment: Is still fine with decimal for backend type?

Comment: @SIBHIS check my updated answer.

Comment: But, deleting the attribute will lead to loss the data from the product. I don't think it would be a better solution. Any other possibilities without losing the data?

Comment: I have a suggestion for you! Before updating, you export the current data cab. And then, upgrade data attribute. Finally, importing data again.

Comment: remove and add not recommended, if product has data associated with this attribute, it will be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
namespace vendor\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface 
{
    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
        ) 
    { 
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    } 

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $entityTypeId = 4;
            $attribute_id = 114;
            $propertyName1 = 'is_filterable';
            $propertyName2 = 'is_filterable_in_search';
            $propertyValue = 1;
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute($entityTypeId,$attribute_id,$propertyName1,1,null); 
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute($entityTypeId,$attribute_id,$propertyName2,1,null);
            $setup->endSetup();
        } 
    } 

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Please use patch file instead of UpgradeData.php**

**app/code/Vendorname/ModuleName/Setup/Patch/Data**

**UpdateProductAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class UpdateProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

        // Update you_attr_code Attribute
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'frontend_input', 'price', null);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'backend_model', 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price');

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'attribute_model', 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $entityType = $eavSetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

        // Revert you_attr_code Attribute
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'frontend_input', 'text', null);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'backend_model', null);

        $eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'you_attr_code', 'attribute_model', null);


        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

> **Here I convert my attribute to price input type**

**For More**: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/patches/