# how to add multi store functionality

Tags: uicomponent, custom-field

i am using Magento 2 , and in my case i have added the ui_components fields , it works fine , but the value entered is applicable to all store view , i want to add multi-store functionality to those fields , the value of a field must be shown just on the store view which i am selected ,

for example :

the field "attribute5", his value entered in storeView English must be different to the storeView Japan

> this is the fields that i have added

file file.xml

this is the patch :

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
          ......
        );
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
           .....
        );
        
        
    }

}
```

> can anyone help please ?

Comment: how did you create the arttributes. Can you post he creation script?

Comment: @Joao71 question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add fields with multi store functionality and save store wise then you need to set scope "store wise" instead of global.

Please change below in your creation script

```
'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
```

If you are working with staging/local server then please remove your attributes from database. Change above thing in script and run setup:upgrade command then try to save values store wise.

Comment: how can i alter the data without deleting the patch from databse please?

Comment: You can do like this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204515/how-to-update-the-attribute-type-in-magento-2

Comment: You can do same way for category attribute -https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/update-product-attribute-patch-data-magento/